# How to find occurrence of element more than 2 in Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

For Example:

```
int[] array={1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3}
```

the array is sorted and each element of array occurred more than two times and return true.
if `int[] array={1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3}` the array is sorted but 1 occur in array only one time should return false.
Following are the code for checking the array is sorted or not , if array is sorted return true if not return false:

```
public class Second {    
    public static void main(String[] args){  
          int[] array = {7,6,3,4,5};   
        boolean sorted = true;  
        for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {  
            if(array[i-1] > array[i]){  
                  sorted = false;  
                  break;  
            }  
        }  
           System.out.println("Sorted: " + sorted);

    }
```

How i achieve my second task in the above code for occurrence of element more than two times should return true, otherwise return false.

Comment: What exactly have you tried yourself for your second task?

Comment: Need assistance how i achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a nested loop to check each element in the array and check it against all the other elements in the array, increment a counter every time you come across the same value. At the end of the inner loop, check if the counter is greater than or equals to 2. If not break the loop.

```
set counter to 0
Repeat i till end of array{
    Repeat j till end of array{
        check if array[j] == array[i]{
            increment the counter
        }
    }
    check if counter<2{
        break;
    }
}
check if counter<2{
    return false;
}
else{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This algorithm handles both requirements at the same time, with a single pass through the array:

- If the array is empty, return whatever the appropriate flag is (`true` or `false`)
- Otherwise (the array isn't empty):

  - Set `previousValue` to the array's first entry
  - Set `previousRepeats` to `false`
  - Loop through the array starting with the second entry:

    - Get the current value as `value`
    - If `value` is equal to `previousValue`, set `previousRepeats` to `true` and start the next loop iteration
    - Otherwise, if `value` is less than `previousValue`, return `false` — the array is not sorted
    - Otherwise, we know `value` is greater than `previousValue`:

      - If `previousRepeats` is `false`, return `false` — you have a value that isn't repeated
      - If that didn't happen, set `previousValue` to `value` and set `previousRepeats` to `false`, and start the next loop iteration
  - When you reach the end of the loop, return the value of the `previousRepeats` flag (to handle the final entry)

If you need to know the *index* of the bad entry, here's a slight modification to the above (changes in **bold**):

Let's assume a return value of `-1` means "all is good", and a return value of `0` or more is the index of the first "bad" entry in the array:

- If the array is empty, return **whatever value is appropriate for a blank array (it's up to you)**
- Otherwise (the array isn't empty):

  - Set `previousValue` to the array's first entry
  - Set `previousRepeats` to `false`
  - Loop through the array starting with the second entry, **keeping track of the array index in `index`**

    - Get the current value as `value`
    - If `value` is equal to `previousValue`, set `previousRepeats` to `true` and start the next loop iteration
    - Otherwise, if `value` is less than `previousValue`, return **`index` — the array is not sorted as of this value**
    - Otherwise, we know `value` is greater than `previousValue`:

      - If `previousRepeats` is `false`, return **`index - 1` — the *previous* entry's value is not repeated, so the "bad" entry is the previous one**
      - If that didn't happen, set `previousValue` to `value` and set `previousRepeats` to `false`, and start the next loop iteration
  - When you reach the end of the loop, **if `previousRepeats` is `true`, return `-1`; otherwise, return `index - 1` to indicate that the final value in the array is not repeated**

Comment: I have done the code for array sorted , what i exactly wanted to find the occurrences of element more than two.

Comment: Still not got my goal.

Comment: If your question is correct, this is your goal. It may not be code you can copy/paste, but it is what you want to do. If you can't write code for this, then you need a tutor and/or a tutorial, but not a Q&A site.

Comment: @JhamanKhatri: Then I misunderstood your comment. What's wrong? You need to know the index of the "bad" entry?

Comment: I got my answer in your discussion thats why i put my question to get different ideas Thanks all for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Have a method that accepts two parameters: your array and the int/entry entry you are looking for multiple occurrences of. Loop through the array and simply keep track of whether the current array index's element == the one you are looking for (your second parameter). If so, increment a counter. If the counter ever exceeds the value you want, return true. Otherwise return false after the loop.

That should help you write the code yourself!

Comment: Put in some effort yourself.